# Globally register component in VueJs with custom Style

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-select

I want to include [Vue-Select](https://vue-select.org) at a VueJs project.

I am implementing a WebPack configuration that exports a `vendors.js` file and a `page.js` for every page I have in this project.

Now Vue-Select is highly parametrizable and I want to keep these settings in a file so it can be used from all my pages and components.

For component parametrizing I use something like this in every component containing `Vue-Select`:

```
    import vSelect from 'vue-select'
    import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';

    vSelect.props.components.default = () => ({
        OpenIndicator: {
            render: createElement => createElement('span', { class: 'select-caret' }),
        },
    });
    Vue.component(vSelect)

    export default {
        components: {
            vSelect //I don't know why i have to include this aswell. 
                    //Vue.component(vSelect) or Vue.use(vSelect) shouldn't be enough?
        },
    }
```

and this custom Style in the component I use it

```
<style>
  span.select-caret {
        width: 14px;
    }

        span.select-caret::after {
            content: ' ';
            border-color: #888 transparent transparent transparent;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 5px 4px 0 4px;
            height: 0;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -4px;
            margin-top: -2px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            width: 0;
        }
</style>
```

Is there a way to add all this in a single file and use only this new `import` in the components that needs `Vue-Select`?

Comment: Normally if you want to re-use code across multiple components in Vue you can use mixins: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: @Djurdjen Thank you for that but I am not sure if this is what i want, I cannot add the stylesheet this way not I can use the default parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It was much simpler than I thought.

I added everything from `Script` to `Style` in a new `.vue` file and included that!

```
<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import vSelect from 'vue-select'
    import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';

    // Set the components prop default to return our fresh components
    vSelect.props.components.default = () => ({
        //Deselect: {
        //    render: createElement => createElement('span', '❌'),
        //},
        OpenIndicator: {
            render: createElement => createElement('span', { class: 'select-caret' }),
        },
    });

    // Register the component
    Vue.component(vSelect)

    //!!! ===== This is really important ==== !!!//
    export default vSelect
</script>

<style>

    .vs__dropdown-toggle {
        border-radius: 0;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 3px 0
    }
</style>
```

And at my component I just used `import` from this new file rather than the original library.

`import vSelect from '../Config/VueSelect.vue'`